# Python GDAL resampling incorrectly: masking actual data points

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, resampling

I am trying to resample GeoTIFF image from 460 m resolution to 500 m using the Python `gdal` library. But somehow GDAL is not resampling correctly. It is also resampling noData values, so resulting images has noData where it should have some data. I have noData values in range of 249 to 255. So, I thought that might be the problem. So, I had assigned all the noData to NaN using np.nan, but I am still having same problem.

I have used `gdal.Translate()` as well as `gdal.Warp()`, but getting same results on both functions.

```
import os
import gdal
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame as df

maskedObj = gdal.Open('maskedLai.tif')

px = 0.004491576420597608
py = -0.004491576420597608
```

GDAL Translate function

```
gdal.Translate('resampled.tif',maskedObj, format='GTiff', outputType=gdal.GDT_Float32, xRes=px, yRes=py, noData=np.nan, resampleAlg='bilinear')
```

GDAL Warp function

```
gdal.Warp('resampled.tif', maskedObj, format='GTiff', outputType=gdal.GDT_Float32, xRes=px, yRes=py, resampleAlg='bilinear', srcNodata=np.nan, dstNodata=np.nan)
```

Here's the maskedLai.tif array before resampling

```
maskedArr = maskedObj.ReadAsArray()
df(maskedArr)
```

[image: Before Resampling Image Array]

Here's the resampled.tif array after resampling

```
resObj = gdal.Open('resampled.tif')
resArr = resObj.ReadAsArray()
df(resArr)
```

[image: After Resampling Image Array]

Here's the visualization of both images.

Before Resampling

[image: wna before resampling]

After Resampling

[image: wna after resampling]

As you can see it has masked the part below San Diego with `NaN`. I am having trouble understanding why GDAL is doing this (irrespective of resampling algorithm). Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What does GDAL think that the nodata value is for your raster?

Comment: I am not sure. Can you tell me how to check or how to set noData value in GDAL?. I have given `noData = np.nan` in `gdal.Translate()` and `gdal.Warp()` function. I am assuming that it will tell GDAL that noData values are NaN.

Comment: As far as I know, `srcNodata=np.nan` and `dstNodata=np.nan` inside the `gdal.Warp()` function tells GDAL that the nodata is NaN.

Comment: I have also tried with original nodata values also where my `srcNodata='249 250 251 252 253 254 255'` and `dstNodata=255`, but having same problem. I have also tried to **change only noData values** using `gdal.Warp()` **no resampling** `gdal.Warp('changedNoData.tif', originalObj, format='GTiff', outputType=gdal.GDT_Float32, srcNodata='249 250 251 252 253 254 255', dstNodata=255)`. It still created same problem, it has change actual data points to 255 and I haven't even done resampling this time.